# How to put a string in a specific index position in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to put the string '^' within a specific index position in my code depending on an awnser, this is my code.

```
mylist = ['', 'O', '']
from random import shuffle

def shuffle_list(mylist):
    shuffle(mylist)
    return mylist


def player_guess():
    guess = ''
    while guess not in ['0', '1', '2']:
        guess = input("Pick a number from 0, 1 or 2: ")

    return int(guess)

myindex = player_guess()

def check_guess(mylist, guess):
    if mylist[guess] == 'O':
        print("Correct")
        print(mylist)
    else:
        print('Wrong guess!')
        correct_pos = {mylist.index('O')}
        print(f"Your guess was at position {guess} the correct position was {correct_pos} \n {mylist} \n")
 

# INITAL LIST
mylist = ['', 'O', '']
# SHUFFLE LIST
mixedup_list = shuffle_list(mylist)
# USER GUESS
guess = player_guess()
# CHECK GUESS
check_guess(mixedup_list, guess)
```

I don't want my output to be this ['','','O'] which is the typical output after you have gotten the question wrong I want it to look like ['','','O']
with the '^' symbol right under the 'O' on a new line, how would I do something like this and what do I need to add?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask a question*. "Would appreciate some help" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). What kind of help is actually needed? What happens when you try your code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? In yout own words, what do you think is the cause of that difference, and why are you unable to solve the problem yourself? Then, taking those things into consideration, ask clearly and precisely, starting with a question word like "how" or "why" and ending with a `?`.

Comment: Also, please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and try to focus your question and the description on the actual *problem you are encountering*.

Comment: Thank you for the response, ill edit my post accordingly. But my question isn't focused on something going wrong rather something I want to accomplish but don't know how so I'm a bit confused on where I went wrong but I will read the articles you have linked.

Comment: If you want to accomplish something, and the code doesn't already accomplish it, then the point in the code where the "something" should be "accomplished", is where the code goes wrong. Try to cut out parts that are irrelevant to accomplishing the thing, but make sure that someone else could copy and paste the code and run it to see the problem.

Comment: Yes thanks for the advice, I changed my explanation a bit and tried to cut as much excess info out as possible trying to get straight to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print out where the O is in the list

```
def check_guess(mylist, guess):
    if mylist[guess] == 'O':
        print("Correct")
        print(mylist)
    else:
        print('Wrong guess!')
        correct_pos = {mylist.index('O')}
        print(f"Your guess was at position {guess} the correct position was {correct_pos} \n {mylist}")
        carrot_string = ' '*(3+mylist.index('O')*4) + '^'
        print(carrot_string)
```

the first element starts at position 3 and increases by 4 depending on where its located in the list

Comment: Thanks for the help, and I have another question if you don't mind. When you run the code even when you input a number between 0 to 2 it will ask you the same question twice, is there a solution to make it not duplicate the phrase even when the correct input is given?

Comment: @Commoq it is because you have `myindex = player_guess()` between the definitions which runs that function twice